# a:hover border not working, border appears under image in the space below?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to use `a:hover` pseduo class so that when you hover over the image, you get a border to appear so that it looks clickable.

However, when I do this the border appears below the image in the space below but I'm unsure why.

```css
#overlay a:hover {
    border: solid 2px #666; 
}
```

[image: Screenshot with incorrect border]

As you can see the border is not around the image, it's below it.

Hope someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: You need to show us the HTML code. Is the `overlay` ID on the `img` attribute?

Comment: @ChrisJ: It can't be, because a `<a>` can't be inside an image, so you'd see no border.

Comment: @ChrisJ The `<img>` wouldn't be wrapped around the `<a>` so the overlay isn't going to be on the image.  My guess is that the `<img>` is floating so the `<a>` is collapsing.

Comment: Yes, you're both right. He needs to show us the code.

Comment: the overlay is the div of the images inside the gallery, i don't want all the images to have the a:hover attribute, only the ones inside this div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the border on the image, not the anchor.

```css
#overlay a:hover img {
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image has `position: relative` or one of the crazy non-block alignments, then the enclosing link doesn't expand to surround it.

We need to see some HTML to be sure, but try to take alignment parameters off the image, and you should it working. If you made the `<a>` `position: relative` I think the link block would surround it.

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to experiment with DOM object layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
#overlay a:hover {
    border: 2px solid #666; 
}
```